# How to make a function that applies different formulas to any length of tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

Sorry about my title, I could not think of a better way to phrase it.
What I am trying to do is make a function that takes a tuple and applies different formulas to each individual number.
My example is take this function:

def 321tup(tup):

And make it so it adds 3 to the first number in the tupple, multiples the 2nd number by 2, and divides the last number by 2. The function will only ever have 3 variables. I realize that I can make a function like

def 321tup(x, y, z):

and make it so it applies the formulas to the variables, but I really need to make it so that it is a tuple and produces a tuple. Any clues how to do this?

Comment: Hmm, I tried to understand what you are after, but I'm lost. Can you be more specific about what part of writing the function you are having trouble with?

Comment: How to write the function so that it takes whatever number you put in the first position of the argument and applies a formula to it, but applies a different formula to the 2nd and 3rd numbers in the argument and outputs a new tuple.

Comment: Do you want to pass these formulas to the function?

Comment: `321tup` is not valid function name - it can't start with a digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? I have not tested this myself yet.

```
def tup321(tup):
    return (tup[0] + 3, tup[1] * 2, tup[2] / 2)
```

Comment: I think that's just the solution to the specific example the author provided.

Comment: @timgeb, that could well be, but given the current ambiguous phrasing, it can hardly be answered more appropriately.

Comment: Wow, this was the solution! I was trying to make two tuples add into each other and making it overly complicated without knowing you could add a tuple and keep it valid. I was always told to do that method so that is what caused the errors. Thank you!

Comment: @Seymour, you're welcome! Do keep zvone's comment in mind though, indeed, functions cannot start with a digit. I updated my code accordingly.

Comment: @Seymour Well, this was confusing. Next time please don't say your are providing an example when that example is exactly what you want, hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question exactly, I guess maybe you want this:

```
from operator import add, mul, div


def tuple_map(tpl, functions):
     return [func(element, element) for element, func in zip(tpl, functions)]

print tuple_map((3, 2, 1), (add, mul, div))
```

output:

```
[6, 4, 1]
```